# I cant deploy an application onto my android

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

The device manager shows that i have no drive for nexus one (it shows a yellow question mark).

Therefore, windows doesnt identify nexus one..even though i can open the folder of the android when i connect the device..

Even HTC Sync application says that no devices is conencted, even thought the device is connected to the pc.

What do i do?

ps. all the settings on android were taken care of..application debuggable mode and allow unknown applications are ticked. The SDK manager is fully updated!!!

UPDATE:
I go to the device manager and tell it to look for the driver here:

D:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver

Thats what the android developer tells me to do:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#WinXp
```

It didnt work..cause i havent got the folder:

```
<sdk>\google-usb_driver\.
```

The guide tells me:

```
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\google-usb_driver\.)
```

Where is teh usb driver that was installed by the sdk manager?

Answer (score 1):

you have to install the driver for you phone ! for the nexus one the driver can be downloaded form the SDK Manager, in the Available packages under Third party addons/Google inc/Google USB Driver Package

Comment: I installed Android composite ADB Interface .. no yellow question mark is shown..did i install the correct driver.... The path you gave me doesnt exist. i cant see my android appearing..should i restart my system?

Comment: it worked finally..thanks..i was right... android guide was wrong